# RefineryCMS inquiries not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, actionmailer, refinerycms

I'm working with an old RefineryCMS 1.0.8 project and migrating it to another server. It all works apart from the contact us form.

Here is my setup in the production.rb file

```
# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
# Defaults to:
# config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
#   location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
#   arguments: '-i -t'
# }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

if ENV['MAILER_USERNAME'].present? && ENV['MAILER_PASSWORD'].present?
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain:  "my_domain.com.au",
    user_name: "#{ENV['MAILER_USERNAME']}",
    password: "#{ENV['MAILER_PASSWORD']}",
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

I've set the environment variables in my /etc/environment and /etc/apache2/envvars files like so;

```
export MAILER_USERNAME="<email address>"
export MAILER_PASSWORD="<password>"
```

I've also set the tld to a length of 2 as we are in Australia so we are using a .com.au. This is set in my config/application.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

Here is the error I get;

```
Sent mail to <my gmail address> (2924ms)
There was an error delivering an inquiry confirmation:
555 5.5.2 Syntax error. w20sm33182626pfi.31 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your email with `<>` blocks?
Do you need a HELO domain? Or can you remove the domain param.
Does it work without the environment variables if you hardcode it in?

Comment: No I'm not, I'll change that example. I haven't changed my A-record yet, maybe I should

Comment: Yeah for the email you need to write it like this `<map7@gmail.com>`

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your email in `<>` blocks.

```
export MAILER_USERNAME="<map@gmail.com>"
export MAILER_PASSWORD="password"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was not the brackets around the email it was the fact that I hadn't setup the DNS to that machine yet. Once I did that last night and went to the refinerycms website at it's domain instead of the IP then I could send emails.